# Can the Needs Answer tab sort by Favorite and Ignored tags like the Home Page?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, homepage, ignored-tags

The Home Page does a good job of bringing up questions that I can answer. However, I suspect that questions get missed and go unanswered, not re-appearing until the next Edit.

I tried using the Needs Answer tab, but there are so many subjects I am not familiar with in there.

[image: Needs Answer tab]

I could re-enter my Favorite Tags, but what about Ignored Tags. I have built a nice and complete Ignored Tags list to filter out specialties I am not familiar with, even if they are in languages I know well.